# Xaringan: Export slides to PDF while preserving formatting

Tags: r, xaringan

I have a Xaringan slide that looks like this:

````
---
title: "Xaringan test"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    self_contained: false
    chakra: 'assets/remark-latest.min.js'
    css: 'assets/presentation.css'
---

### This is a heading

This is some text and numbers 01235.

`Here is some inline code`.

```
block code
```

```{r}
cat("Some R code")
```

$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
````

---

The rendered HTML looks like below. Custom font, CSS styles and mathjax all render well. This is how it is intended to look.

[image]

---

Exporting to PDF using Pagedown.

```
pagedown::chrome_print("test.html",output="test.pdf")
```

[image]

The custom font and css styles are preserved. The default code font has changed and the mathjax expression is not displayed. Apart from the missing mathjax, it is doing a pretty good job.

---

Exporting to PDF using webshot.

```
webshot("test.html","test.pdf")
```

[image]

Custom font and css styles are not preserved. The default code font and mathjax is preserved.

---

Anyone got any tips on how to preserve fonts, CSS style and mathjax while exporting to PDF through function?

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
webshot_0.5.1      
pagedown_0.1
xaringan_0.8
```

Comment: I've heard good things about `decktape` and it was brought into xaringan.  [related discussion](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/168)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT**: We've renamed the package to "renderthis" to be more general and to support other presentation types, such as Quarto presentations: https://github.com/jhelvy/renderthis

Instead of `build_*()`, the function names all start with `to_*()`, e.g.

```r
renderthis::to_pdf("slides.Rmd")
```

---

I've been building on a package that builds xaringan slides to multiple output types: html, pdf, pptx, gif, and a couple options for a png of the first slide. It should render to PDFs well.

https://github.com/jhelvy/xaringanBuilder

### Install the package

```r
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("jhelvy/xaringanBuilder")

library(xaringanBuilder)
```

### Build a pdf file from a Rmd or html file:

```r
build_pdf("slides.Rmd")
build_pdf("slides.html")
```

### Include "Complex" or partial slides:

“Complex” slides are slides that contain
[panelsets](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/#/panelset) or
other html widgets / advanced features that might not render well as a
pdf. To render these, set `complex_slides = TRUE`. If you want to build a
new slide for each increment on [incremental
slides](https://slides.yihui.org/xaringan/incremental.html#1), set
`partial_slides = TRUE`.

```r
build_pdf("slides.Rmd", complex_slides = TRUE, partial_slides = TRUE)
build_pdf("slides.html", complex_slides = TRUE, partial_slides = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is very cool. Just curious if it handles the slide notes somehow?

Comment: That's a good idea! I think I could implement that, I'll post the idea as an issue.

Comment: Thanks! This package will make remark slides easier to share as pdf for my students

Comment: FYI, slide notes / slides with handouts are in the works, see this PR: https://github.com/jhelvy/xaringanBuilder/pull/34

Comment: Wow, that's impressive! Definitely something to implement in the xaringan package imo. Thanks a lot @jhelvy

Answer (score 5):

At this moment, you have to use the development versions of **pagedown** and **xaringan**: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/168#issuecomment-461638520

Comment: Dang! I should've checked the github issues. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I plan to release the new version of **xaringan** to CRAN soon.