# R Markdown missing plots when I print to PDF from xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdf-generation, knitr, xaringan

[This stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968311/xaringan-export-slides-to-pdf-while-preserving-formatting) describes a method (through the xaringanBuilder package) to build your xaringan slides to various formats (html, pdf, pptx, etc). Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue I'm having:

````r
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

# xaringan plot that won't print to pdf

```{r cars, fig.height=4, dev='svg'}
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$hp)
plot(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt)
plot(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$vs)
```
````

When I knit the xaringan R Markdown code above it works as expected:

1. A plot is generated consisting of four figures.
2. I can view the HTML in my browsers (Edge, Chrome)

I then proceed to *print to PDF* from Edge (or Chrome), the PDF is generated, and the plots are missing from the output. I've made sure to enable *include background graphics* when printing to pdf. Why do the plots go missing, and how do I keep the plots in the PDF output?

[Building with xaringanBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54968311/xaringan-export-slides-to-pdf-while-preserving-formatting) doesn't solve the issue either, the plot is still missing from the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A little intro:**

As I came to the conclusion in the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538109/print-xaringan-slides-with-presenter-notes/73544055#73544055) in order to "activate" print function in `xaringan` presentation - one needs to add `@media print` css rule.

Returning to your question and adding `@media print` rule - we can see the next results.

**Code:**

````
---
title: "Presentation"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader: default
---

<style>
@media print{
  body, html, .remark-slides-area, .remark-notes-area {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: visible;
    display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

# xaringan plot which prints to pdf

```{r cars, fig.height=4, dev='svg', echo = F}
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$hp)
plot(mtcars$drat, mtcars$wt)
plot(mtcars$qsec, mtcars$vs)
```
````

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: that CSS works good, however the pdf output plots are a smaller than the same HTML plots, is there a way to get the sizes identical?

Comment: @jophuh Ye, you can control the plot size. Look [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/figure_sizing_knitr/) You can adjust output for every slide for the better look. I prefer to use ```out.width/height``` instead of ```fig.width/height```